# USQL, extracting foldername into output

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to extract a folder name from `data lake` store and outputting that as a column into `csv` file. Is there a way to extract the entire folder name or parts of the folder name through `USQL`? For example `/input/Testing` - I want the `Testing`.

I know you can extract the file name and put it into a virtual column like this:

```
// Filesets, file set with virtual column

@q =
EXTRACT rowId int,
        filename string,
        extension string
FROM "/input/filesets example/{filename}.{extension}"
USING Extractors.Tsv();


@output =
SELECT filename,
       extension,
       COUNT( * ) AS records
FROM @q
GROUP BY filename,
         extension;


OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

[See pic here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se31q.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `{virtual_column}` functionality in any place within the path (not just for filename and extension), and project it later on. This will work:

```
@q = EXTRACT 
       rowId int,
       folder string,
       filename string,
       extension string
    FROM "/input/{folder}/{filename}.{extension}"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();

@output =
    SELECT folder,
       filename,
       extension,
       COUNT( * ) AS records
    FROM @q
    GROUP BY folder,
         filename,
         extension;
```

However, note that by using virtual column within path you are also getting wildcard functionality (you will pickup all the folders in case you have more than one)...

Comment: Have a predicate on the virtual column to ensure you only get the folder you want, eg `WHERE folder == "yourFolder";`

Comment: When i try to run the above code, it says Virtual Column 'folder' is not defined in the EXTRACT statement.

Comment: When i try to run the above code, I added folder string in the extract statement and my results came back with an empty input..

Comment: Yes, the folder column was missing in EXTRACT, fixed it... I didn't get what's the other problem though, could you share the script?